# Automate Maven within Eclipse + Change .jar export destination

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

My situation: I have a java project in eclipse. I have recently added the Maven plugin to my eclipse IDE.

In order for Maven to export my .jar, I have to right click my project > run as >  Maven Clean. Then I have to right click my project > Maven > update project. Then I have to right click my project > run as > Maven install. Must be done in this order and skipping the middle step will produce errors with no successful .jar file.
So my first question is can I automate this within eclipse? If not, can I simplify this process?

My second question is, can I specify the destination folder of that exported .jar to anywhere on my computer?
So for instance Maven normally exports the .jar to `D:\${eclipse.workspace}\${project.name}\target\` but I would like to export it to `D:\Programs\`. Once again, this must be done from within eclipse. It would be preferable if the solution could simply make a copy from `\target\` to `\programs` or have a second directory output.

I've briefly (as in spent the better part of my day) looked at pom.xml configurations and Ant build tool but am not sure if I'm chasing a dead end.

Appreciate any and all help given!

Answer (score 0):

@SethFul;
Right click the project (or POM file) -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> Maven Build -> write in the profiles box the actions you want: "clean install" -> run.

That will perform both actions at once.

Changing the output dir is also feasible; take a look at [this question][1]

[1]: [How to change maven build directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587375/how-to-change-maven-build-directory) ... hope you find the answer there.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply! While I was not able to immediately find a solution to my questions with your responses, they did contribute to the eventual answer to my problems. The first response you gave was what I was looking for, however the middle step (Right click project > Maven > update project) could not be resolved this way. Thanks in kind sir.

Answer (score 0):

(1)The solution to the first question (credit to @Diego Vill),  is: Right click project -> Run As -> Run Configurations... -> Maven Build. In the "Goals" textbox put "clean install". Click Apply.

(2)To solve the problem of having to right click project -> Maven ->  Update Project. I removed this step, having Maven Clean and Install(See 1). This would throw an error, stating that it was missing a tools.jar. I followed this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163021/maven-in-eclipse-complains-that-unable-to-locate-the-javac-compiler-whenever-p) by Isuru chathuranga to resolve the problem.

The solution to my second question is in this [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html). This would allow me to copy my .jar after it was exported, and place the copy in another directory. All done within Eclipse.

(Note 2, for an explanation on why I needed to constantly Update Project after modifying any project files see dmiandres answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532534/maven-why-after-mvn-clean-i-need-to-execute-maven-update-project-before-m))